Proof that the order of a linear prediction model cannot be reduced by analysing non-adjacent points
I have a signal, for which a linear prediction model of order $M$ can be constructed. This means, that a system of the shape
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s_0 & s_1 & \cdots & s_M \\
s_1 & s_2 & \cdots & s_{M + 1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
s_{N - M -1} & s_{N - M} & \cdots & s_{N - 1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 \\
c_1 \\
\vdots \\
c_M
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank $M$ and thus, only one basis vector for a solution. If we extend the system matrix to be $K + 1$ columns wide instead of $M + 1$, we get solutions of the shape
$$
\overline{c}_n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\vdots \\
c_0 \\
\vdots \\
c_M \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $n$ is the position at which non-zero members begin in the column vector. In other words, we get the initial solution, concatenated with zeros on both ends. The number of such solutions is $K - M + 1$, while the length of them is just $K + 1$. The number of these solutions corresponds to the difference between the size of the system and its rank. Also, it is easy to see that they are linearly independent by just calculating a determinant of the lower-triangular submatrix, where the bottom $M$ rows are truncated:
$$
\det [c] =
\begin{vmatrix}
c_0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
c_1 & c_0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & c_0
\end{vmatrix} = c_0^{K - M + 1}.
$$
This means, that I've found the whole solution basis and all other solutions are a linear combinations of these column vectors.
The question I have is this: how can I prove, that there are no linear combinations of the solution basis, that can leave me with less than $M + 1$ non-zero linear prediction coefficients? In other words, how can I prove, that it is impossible to reduce the order of the linear prediction problem by using non-adjacent points when sampling the data? I was able to prove to myself that it is impossible to reduce the order of the problem for adjacent points, but the general case eludes me still. I feel like I am stuck because I am looking into the linear combination of the solutions too much and not noticing some elegant outside-of-the-box solution.
If there is anything I can add to make my question better, I would gladly do it. Thanks to everyone in advance.

I hadn't thunked that LPC is the same as fitting a $M^\mathrm{th}$ -order polynomial to $M+1$ points.  They're similar problems I guess but the polynomial fit problem does not specify anything about the expected power spectrum (or autocorrelation) of the signal.

Yeah, this problem can also be posed as "Prove, that the greatest common divisor of 2 polynomials which have M+1 coefficients cannot be of order larger than M", if I understand it correctly.
